# AVA Test Fails in case of accessing global variable

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js, ava

We've recently started migrating tests for database models.

Facing an issue while trying to separate out different type of tests in different files.

I am writing some [AVA](https://github.com/avajs/ava) unit tests
In one file test_1.js
it is,

```
const test = require('ava');

const sDB = require('../services/serviceDB');

const config = require('../../config').production;
const { CONFIG_RDS } = config;


let x = 1;

test.before(async (t) => {
  t.context.log = console.log;
// following line connects with database and sets global.db
    await loaderDB.connect(CONFIG);

  })

test('Test 1 - to access database',async(t)=>{
    // test some functionality that accesses global.db
    // it passes
})
```

On the other file test_2.js

```
const test = require('ava');

const sDB = require('../services/serviceDB');

const config = require('../../config').production;
const { CONFIG_RDS } = config;


let x = 1;

test.before(async (t) => {
  t.context.log = console.log;
  // wait for db to be connected
   await timeout(4000) // custom timeout that awaits

  })

test('Test 2 - to access database',async(t)=>{
    // test some functionality that accesses global.db
    // it FAILS
    // It returns exception that global.db is undefined
})
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each test file runs in its own process, so you need to connect to the database in each test file.

Comment: thanks.
I have tried that using `.before` , but the database initialisation actually sets a global variable `global.db`. so when i try run the tests that uses `global.db` from a different file it fails to read from that.

Comment: Yes, because each file runs in its own process.